# VMWare workstation 15 Pro pn Ubuntu 18.4.03 LTS - Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I'm facing a failure to run any instance on VWMware Workstation 15 Pro on Ubuntu 18.4.03 LTS.

I have followed the previous [VMWare 15 Error on Ubuntu 18.4 - Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096052/vmware-15-error-on-ubuntu-18-4-could-not-open-dev-vmmon-no-such-file-or-dire) step by step. But still I still having the same errors which are listed below.

When I arrive at testing the driver / module installed correctly:

```
$ mokutil --test-key VMWARE15.der
```

You should get `VMWARE15.der is already enrolled` but I get `VMWARE15.der is not enrolled`

```
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
[sudo] password for user:
[AppLoader] Use shipped Linux kernel AIO access library.
An up-to-date "libaio" or "libaio1" package from your system is preferred.
[AppLoader] GLib does not have GSettings support.
Stopping VMware services:
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   Virtual machine monitor                                             done
   Blocking file system                                                done
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-70-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driverLog.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/memtrack.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/apic.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/statVarsVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/sharedAreaVmmon.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/cpuid.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/comport.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/phystrack.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:134:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:632:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:633:0: warning: "MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT" redefined
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT                      0x0000010f

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:641:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT  0x0000010F

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:44,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:45:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:5:0,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:5:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.c:71:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:44,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:92,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.c:71:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:632:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.c:51:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:134:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:92,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/mmu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/desc.h:7,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.c:71:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:641:0: warning: "MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT" redefined
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT  0x0000010F

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/common/task.c:51:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:633:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT                      0x0000010f

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoaderVmmon.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:33,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:47:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:134:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:92,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:632:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.h:33,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:47:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:633:0: warning: "MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT" redefined
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT                      0x0000010f

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/paravirt_types.h:46,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h:92,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/math_emu.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:12,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:641:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT  0x0000010F

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:43:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:60:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:134:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/binfmts.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:632:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:43:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:60:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:633:0: warning: "MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT" redefined
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT                      0x0000010f

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/binfmts.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:641:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT  0x0000010F

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:44,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:60:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:5:0,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from ./include/linux/binfmts.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c:32:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm_x86.h:41:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/vm_asm.h:44,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:49:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86_basic_defs.h:78:0: warning: "CR3_PCID_MASK" redefined
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK  0xFFF

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:5:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/cpufeature.h:5,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:53,
                 from ./include/linux/thread_info.h:38,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:7,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:81,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from ./include/linux/wait.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/wait_bit.h:8,
                 from ./include/linux/fs.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/highmem.h:5,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:25:
./arch/x86/include/asm/processor-flags.h:39:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define CR3_PCID_MASK 0xFFFull

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/bootstrap/monLoader.o
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c: In function ‘LinuxDriver_Ioctl’:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:1536:5: warning: "VMX86_DEVEL" is not defined, evaluates to 0 [-Wundef]
 #if VMX86_DEVEL
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
At top level:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/linux/driver.c:961:1: warning: always_inline function might not be inlinable [-Wattributes]
 LinuxDriverSyncReadTSCs(uint64 *delta) // OUT: TSC max - TSC min
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/bootstrap/vmmblob.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.c:35:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:134:0: warning: "MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES" redefined
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES            0x140

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:632:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_MISC_FEATURES_ENABLES 0x00000140

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./common/vmx86.h:32:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.c:35:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/./include/x86msr.h:633:0: warning: "MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT" redefined
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT                      0x0000010f

In file included from ./arch/x86/include/asm/nospec-branch.h:11:0,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/irqflags.h:9,
                 from ./include/linux/irqflags.h:16,
                 from ./include/linux/rcupdate.h:39,
                 from ./include/linux/rculist.h:11,
                 from ./include/linux/pid.h:5,
                 from ./include/linux/sched.h:14,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmcore/moduleloop.c:31:
./arch/x86/include/asm/msr-index.h:641:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define MSR_TSX_FORCE_ABORT  0x0000010F

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/bootstrap/bootstrap.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmmon.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmmon.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only/vmmon.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-70-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only'
cp -f vmmon.ko ./../vmmon.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmmon-only'
make: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only'
Using kernel build system.
/usr/bin/make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-70-generic/build/include/.. SUBDIRS=$PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-70-generic'
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/driver.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/hub.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/userif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/netif.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/bridge.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/procfs.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/smac_compat.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/smac.o
  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vnetEvent.o
In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/netif.c:44:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2265:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/netif.c:44:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2266:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/netif.c:43:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:74:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

  CC [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vnetUserListener.o
In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:56:0: warning: "PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE" redefined
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE                    0x15AD

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2265:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_VENDOR_ID_VMWARE  0x15ad

In file included from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/net.h:38:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vnetInt.h:26,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/bridge.c:53:
/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vm_device_version.h:74:0: warning: "PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3" redefined
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3            0x07B0

In file included from ./include/linux/pci.h:37:0,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/compat_netdevice.h:27,
                 from /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/bridge.c:52:
./include/linux/pci_ids.h:2266:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define PCI_DEVICE_ID_VMWARE_VMXNET3 0x07b0

  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vmnet.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vmnet.mod.o
  LD [M]  /tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only/vmnet.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-70-generic'
/usr/bin/make -C $PWD SRCROOT=$PWD/. \
  MODULEBUILDDIR= postbuild
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only'
make[1]: 'postbuild' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only'
cp -f vmnet.ko ./../vmnet.o
make: Leaving directory '/tmp/modconfig-FZko6r/vmnet-only'
Starting VMware services:
   Virtual machine monitor                                            failed
   Virtual machine communication interface                             done
   VM communication interface socket family                            done
   Blocking file system                                                done
   Virtual ethernet                                                   failed
   VMware Authentication Daemon                                        done
Unable to start services
```

These are the errors I'm getting after launching VMWare:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

[image: Error 3]

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution!

[ubuntu-vmmon-vmware-bash](https://github.com/rune1979/ubuntu-vmmon-vmware-bash)

**ubuntu-vmmon-vmware-bash**

Simple bash script for updating MOK keys for VMWare in Ubuntu (and probably other Debian based distributions): Typical error occurs when attempting to boot virtual machine in VMWare "Cannot open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory".

Why automate this process? You may ask. In my case I don't want to make a complete reinstall and I'm not even sure it will work. And every time I patch my Debian based system it seems like the MOK keys loss their privileges.

After this setup I just open the terminal and execute the following command (./wm_autoupdate_key.sh) in the terminal, when VMWare complain about "vmmon"

1. Open your terminal en paste the following command (it will get the bash script to your current dir)

   ```
   wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rune1979/ubuntu-vmmon-vmware-bash/master/wm_autoupdate_key.sh
   ```
2. Make the file executable

   ```
   sudo chmod +x wm_autoupdate_key.sh
   ```
3. Execute the script

   ```
   ./wm_autoupdate_key.sh
   ```

If everything seems to work out successfully. You should now ($ reboot) your machine and choose "Enroll MOK" in the blue menu and follow the instructions and reboot. After that your VMWare should be up and running again.

Next time: you have patched your OS, just navigate to the script folder in your terminal and execute the script:

```
    ./wm_autoupdate_key.sh
```

Comment: yeah, vmware17 on ubuntu 20.04, I do it 2-3 times and it worked with secure boot enabled